# Ajax Response HTML Response

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I am trying to check for duplicates existing at Entry and alert user with a message inline that the number exists.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#con1").blur(function(){
        $.ajax({
        datatype: 'text',
        url: "check-dup-num.php",
        data : {
            con1: $("#con1").val()
            },
        context: document.body,
        success: function(result){
            console.log (result);
        }
    });
    });
});
```

This returns the following in console log.

```
{"numcount":"3"}
```

What I need is to populate div id=#con1 with a message :

```
<p> 3 duplicates found </p>
```

if the numcount is not equal to 0.

I tried adding

```
    var counter = $.parseJSON('result');
    var container = $('<p class="con1error"></p>');
    for(var i=0; i < counter.items.length; i++) {
     container.append('<p> Found ' + counter.items[i].numcount + ' duplicates. </h5>');
    }           
    $('#con1').append(container);
```

But to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in the response to suggest that there's an `items` array, and there's no reason for having a loop.

Simply:

```
var counter = $.parseJSON('result'); // You may or may not need to do this
// Remove any previous message
$('#con1 .con1error').remove();
if (counter.numcount != 0) {
    // Set a message
    $('#con1').append("<p class=con1error> Found " + counter.numcount + " duplicate(s). </p>");
}
```

A couple of other notes about your `ajax` call:

- You have `datatype: 'text'`. The option is `dataType`, not `datatype`. Case matters. But normally, you don't want to specify `dataType` at all. Instead, ensure the response comes back with an appropriate `Content-Type` and jQuery will use that to figure out what to do.
- There's no need for `context: document.body` unless you really want `this` in your callbacks to refer to `document.body`, which would be unusual.
- If you ensure that the PHP response has the correct `Content-Type` (`application/json`), then you don't need or want the `$.parseJSON` call. jQuery will see the content type and parse it before giving it to you. You only need the `$.parseJSON` call if your PHP response has an incorrect `Content-Type` like `text/plain` or `text/html`.

Comment: I just did this:

var counter = result;
   if (counter.numcount == 0) {
    $('#con1').empty();
   } else {
    alert("Found " + counter.numcount + " duplicate(s)");
    $('#con1').append("<p> Found " + counter.numcount + " duplicate(s). </p>");
   }

Now it says "Found undefined duplicates".

Comment: This works. After implementing the edit in totality. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Can we use an alternative to append? Because, every time onblur, the error message replicates.

Comment: @Lenrox - It doesn't with the code above. The code above removes any previous one before (possibly) adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that `result` is equal to `{"numcount":"3"}`

In the success callback you can call the following.

**In VanillaJS:**

```
document.getElementById("con1").innerHTML = result["numcount"] + "duplicates found";
```

**In jQuery:**

```
$("#con1").html(result["numcount"] + "duplicates found");
```

**Your code would look something like this:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#con1").blur(function(){
        $.ajax({
        datatype: 'text',
        url: "check-dup-num.php",
        data : {
            con1: $("#con1").val()
            },
        context: document.body,
        success: function(result){
            console.log (result);
            //this will populate div id=#con1 with the message
            document.getElementById("con1").innerHTML = result["numcount"] + "duplicates found";
        }
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: Albeit I didn't use this answer, but wondering why was this downvoted?